# How to fix ping issues whenever a tiny bit of bandwidth is being used with or without QoS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, gaming

I have a Linksys Smart-Wifi router and I have an internet speed of 4Mb/s. Whenever someone is using more than 0.6Mb/s the ping in games, such as Overwatch, jumps from 80ms to around 160+. This makes games unplayable. I am plugged into Ethernet.

I've heard of something called QoS, and my router doesn't seem to have such a thing except something called "Application Prioritizing".

[image]

It accepts 4 ranges of ports that you can select between UDP, TCP, and both.
According to the blizzard forums, there are these ports:

**TCP**: 1119, 3724, 6113, 80
**UDP**: 3478-3479, 5060, 5062, 6250, 12000-64000

Which ones do I use? Will this solve my issues? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: please share exact model to take a look at the user guide. QoS (quality of service) is indeed used to give a certain preference to traffic that is highly susceptible to latency such as games and VoIP (voice over IP), so based on the "Application Prioritizing" image you have shared it may help overcome the issue you are having to a certain degree, that is until some other application starts drawing more bandwidth usage, hence checking the specs/ details of that device will greatly help me to provide you a more detailed and informed answer to whether this configuration gives a solid guarantee.

Comment: @DRP Linksys wrt 1900 AC

Answer (score 0):

Answer is *Yes*, this feature will help, however take it with a grain of salt as there are other elements out of your  control, see reasoning below.

[User guide download here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiq-Lz_8tfYAhXuk-AKHUy6DSMQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloads.linksys.com%2Fdownloads%2Fuserguide%2F1224701614608%2FMAN_WRT1900AC_8820-01897_RevA00_EN_FR-CA_Comprehensive.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3fFRkmrnzv0aTmLtA3aHrn)

From the guide there are two key statements:

> Prioritization settings are applied only to traffic that is uploaded
>   to the Internet. The router cannot control the quality of the traffic
>   after it reaches the Internet.
>
> ---
>
> Caution: If you specify a maximum bandwidth that is too high, the
>   router cannot apply priorities correctly, and prioritization problems
>   may result.

Checking elsewhere some people ran into issues when defining the media prioritization config, which I don't think you are running into, however [this link](https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/How-does-Media-Prioritization-work/td-p/704735) might be useful.

Unfortunately the User guide is very basic in providing details of how things work under the hood, and my thoughts have indeed been confirmed, how to quantify the amount of traffic that is being prioritized and how to further understand more in-depth the inner workings of this type of setup.

The information below came useful:
["it's pretty hard to objectively quantify the effect of the 'Media Prioritization' settings"](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/linksys-wrt1900ac-media-prioritization.17138/)

On this last hyperlink there is also discussion about the service being traffic shaping and not QoS in case you are very picky on the use of terms.

From the Lynksis community support you can broadly define the workings as such:

- Downstream bandwidth is the maximum amount of bandwidth your ISP provides you.
- Devices listed a High Priority will be given what they require from the Downstream bandwidth.
- Devices listed as Low Priority are given what bandwidth is left over after the High Priority devices.
- All devices never exceed the Downstream bandwidth maximum. So if you set it at 512 kbps all devices regardless of their priority will never get more that 512 kbps.

Comment: So what ports do I use then?

Comment: @Ab_ after a brief checking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers it appears that many of this ports are used by Blizzard games, more digging would be needed to define what each one is used for, hence use all ports, if you run out of port range fields, just add a new game to define the other ports. i.e game1-tcp and game2-udp or whatever naming convention works

Comment: Yes, but there is a range, not a number. How do I use those numbers? I have [field] to [field], but I only have the number 1119, not a range

Comment: @Ab_ put the same number in both fields.  [1119] to [1119]